# Property or indexer 'IdentityUser<int, ApplicationUserLogin,ApplicationUserRole,ApplicationUserClaim>.Roles' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

I'm working on MVC5 with Identity 1.0 Entity Framework web application. In my seed method I'm trying to assign roles to my user during the first migration. 
I get an error when I put

```
Role = "Admin"
```

> Property or Indexer 'IdentityUserApplicationUserLogin,ApplicationUserRole,ApplicationUserClaim>.Roles' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only

Does this mean I have to assign the role manually on the website when I run the application?

Configuration.cs

```
     var roles = new List<ApplicationRole>
        {
            new ApplicationRole { Id = 1,  Name = "Admin"},
            new ApplicationRole { Id = 2,  Name = "User"},

        };
        roles.ForEach(s => context.Roles.AddOrUpdate(p => p.Name, s));
        context.SaveChanges();


        var passwordHash = new PasswordHasher();
        string password = passwordHash.HashPassword("Password@123");

        var users = new List<ApplicationUser>
        {

            new ApplicationUser { UserName = "jackie@hotmail.com", FirstMidName = "Jackie", LastName = "Chan", Email="jasonw@rs.kiwi.nz",PasswordHash = password, Roles = "Admin",
                EnrollmentDate = DateTime.Parse("2016-02-18"), DepartmentID = 1,DepotID = 1,IsAdministrator = true,SecurityStamp = Guid.NewGuid().ToString()},


        users.ForEach(s => context.Users.AddOrUpdate(p => p.UserName, s));
        context.SaveChanges();
```

IdentityModel.cs

```
namespace RecreationalServicesTicketingSystem.Models
{
    public class ApplicationUserLogin : IdentityUserLogin<int> { }
    public class ApplicationUserClaim : IdentityUserClaim<int> { }
    public class ApplicationUserRole : IdentityUserRole<int> { }

    public class ApplicationRole : IdentityRole<int, ApplicationUserRole>, IRole<int>
    {
        public string Description { get; set; }

        public ApplicationRole() : base() { }
        public ApplicationRole(string name)
            : this()
        {
            this.Name = name;
        }

        public ApplicationRole(string name, string description)
            : this(name)
        {
            this.Description = description;
        }
    }

    public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser<int, ApplicationUserLogin, ApplicationUserRole, ApplicationUserClaim>, IUser<int>
    {
        public async Task<ClaimsIdentity>
            GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser, int> manager)
        {
            var userIdentity = await manager
                .CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
            return userIdentity;
        }

        public bool IsAdministrator { get; set; }
        [StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 1)]

        public string LastName { get; set; }
        [StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 1, ErrorMessage = "First name cannot be longer than 50 characters.")]

        [Column("FirstName")]
        public string FirstMidName { get; set; }

        public string FullName
        {
            get { return FirstMidName + " " + LastName; }
        }
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public DateTime EnrollmentDate { get; set; }
        public int DepartmentID { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("DepartmentID")]
        public virtual Department Department { get; set; }
        public int DepotID { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("DepotID")]
        public virtual Depot Depot { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Ticket> Tickets { get; set; }


    }


    public class ApplicationDbContext
        : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole, int,
        ApplicationUserLogin, ApplicationUserRole, ApplicationUserClaim>
    {
         public ApplicationDbContext()
            : base("DefaultConnection")
        {
        }

        static ApplicationDbContext()
        {
            Database.SetInitializer<ApplicationDbContext>(new ApplicationDbInitializer());
        }


        public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
        {
            return new ApplicationDbContext();
        }


        public DbSet<Ticket> Tickets { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Department> Departments { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Depot> Depots { get; set; }


    }



    public class ApplicationUserStore :
    UserStore<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole, int,
    ApplicationUserLogin, ApplicationUserRole, ApplicationUserClaim>, IUserStore<ApplicationUser, int>, IDisposable
    {
        public ApplicationUserStore()
            : this(new IdentityDbContext())
        {
            base.DisposeContext = true;
        }

        public ApplicationUserStore(DbContext context)
            : base(context)
        {
        }
    }


    public class ApplicationRoleStore
    : RoleStore<ApplicationRole, int, ApplicationUserRole>,
    IQueryableRoleStore<ApplicationRole, int>,
    IRoleStore<ApplicationRole, int>, IDisposable
    {
        public ApplicationRoleStore()
            : base(new IdentityDbContext())
        {
            base.DisposeContext = true;
        }

        public ApplicationRoleStore(DbContext context)
            : base(context)
        {
        }
    }

}
```

Roles Controller

```
namespace RecreationalServicesTicketingSystem.Controllers
{
    //[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
    public class RolesAdminController : Controller
    {

         public RolesAdminController()
        {

        }

        public RolesAdminController(ApplicationUserManager userManager,
            ApplicationRoleManager roleManager)
        {
            UserManager = userManager;
            RoleManager = roleManager;
        }

        private ApplicationUserManager _userManager;
        public ApplicationUserManager UserManager
        {
            get
            {
                return _userManager ?? HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
            }
            set
            {
                _userManager = value;
            }
        }

        private ApplicationRoleManager _roleManager;
        public ApplicationRoleManager RoleManager
        {
            get
            {
                return _roleManager ?? HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Get<ApplicationRoleManager>();
            }
            private set
            {
                _roleManager = value;
            }
        }

        //
        // GET: /Roles/
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(RoleManager.Roles);
        }

        //
        // GET: /Roles/Details/5
        public async Task<ActionResult> Details(int id)
        {
            if (id > 0)
            {
                var role = await RoleManager.FindByIdAsync(id);
                // Get the list of Users in this Role
                var users = new List<ApplicationUser>();

                // Get the list of Users in this Role
                foreach (var user in UserManager.Users.ToList())
                {
                    if (await UserManager.IsInRoleAsync(user.Id, role.Name))
                    {
                        users.Add(user);
                    }
                }

                ViewBag.Users = users;
                ViewBag.UserCount = users.Count();
                return View(role);
            }
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }

        //
        // GET: /Roles/Create
        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }

        //
        // POST: /Roles/Create
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Create(RoleViewModel roleViewModel)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                // Use ApplicationRole, not IdentityRole:
                var role = new ApplicationRole(roleViewModel.Name);
                var roleresult = await RoleManager.CreateAsync(role);
                if (!roleresult.Succeeded)
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", roleresult.Errors.First());
                    return View();
                }
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return View();
        }

        //
        // GET: /Roles/Edit/Admin
        public async Task<ActionResult> Edit(int id)
        {
            if (id > 0)
            {
                var role = await RoleManager.FindByIdAsync(id);
                if (role == null)
                {
                    return HttpNotFound();
                }
                RoleViewModel roleModel = new RoleViewModel { Id = role.Id, Name = role.Name };
                return View(roleModel);
            }
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }

        //
        // POST: /Roles/Edit/5
        [HttpPost]

        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Edit([Bind(Include = "Name,Id")] RoleViewModel roleModel)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var role = await RoleManager.FindByIdAsync(roleModel.Id);
                role.Name = roleModel.Name;
                await RoleManager.UpdateAsync(role);
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return View();
        }

        //
        // GET: /Roles/Delete/5
        public async Task<ActionResult> Delete(int id)
        {
            if (id > 0)
            {
                var role = await RoleManager.FindByIdAsync(id);
                if (role == null)
                {
                    return HttpNotFound();
                }
                return View(role);
            }
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }

        //
        // POST: /Roles/Delete/5
        [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<ActionResult> DeleteConfirmed(int id, string deleteUser)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                if (id > 0)
                {
                    var role = await RoleManager.FindByIdAsync(id);
                    if (role == null)
                    {
                        return HttpNotFound();
                    }
                    IdentityResult result;
                    if (deleteUser != null)
                    {
                        result = await RoleManager.DeleteAsync(role);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        result = await RoleManager.DeleteAsync(role);
                    }
                    if (!result.Succeeded)
                    {
                        ModelState.AddModelError("", result.Errors.First());
                        return View();
                    }
                    return RedirectToAction("Index");
                }
                else
                {
                    return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
                }
            }
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The roles property of your new ApplicationUser object expects an iCollection of ApplicationUserRole items. See example below.

```
new ApplicationUser
{
    UserName = "jackie@hotmail.com",
    FirstMidName = "Jackie",
    LastName = "Chan",
    Email = "jasonw@rs.kiwi.nz",
    PasswordHash = password,
    Roles =
    {
        new ApplicationUserRole
        {
            RoleId = 1
        }
    },
    EnrollmentDate = DateTime.Parse("2016-02-18"),
    DepartmentID = 1,
    DepotID = 1,
    IsAdministrator = true,
    SecurityStamp = Guid.NewGuid().ToString()
}
```